# field size limitation of csv file

Tags: csv

I was wondering if there is a limit to the size of a single field that can be saved in a csv file? I understand that the size of the CSV file itself is dependent only on the operating system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The history of CSV is described at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). The closest thing to a formal specification of the CSV file format is [RFC4180](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt).

Neither of these documents describe any limits on the size of a field. In practice the tooling you use might have some sort of restriction, as most CSV parsers would buffer the record line, prior to splitting it.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I needed a confirmation. And thanks for the RFC link!

Answer (score 12):

[Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)
Excel cannot read more than 32767 characters in a single cell. Total number of characters that a cell can contain: 32,767 characters

Answer (score 5):

"The new" Google Sheets limits you to 50,000 characters / field. You get an error message (see below) if you try to paste more than that.

If you upload a .csv there is no warning, but the offending field and all following fields in that row are dropped.

[image: sheets error message]

Comment: When I open a csv file in libre calc, it says "maximum character limit in a cell exceeded". However, it works fine in ms-excel. It gives error even if a cell has less than 500 characters