# What is the maximum length of a column in csv file?

Tags: java, csv

What is the maximum length of a column in csv file. Is it controllable by java code?

Comment: Who said there is a maximum length ?

Comment: @gdoron I would say you can't have a column longer than the size of your hard drive. ;)

Comment: Yes, now I see. Anyway, it doesn't mention maximum size of column in its specification at [rfc4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)

Comment: Interesting RFC. Neverk knew there was MIME recommendations for csv files. Especially like the header=present|absent. Learn something new every day... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [field size limitation of csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971542/field-size-limitation-of-csv-file)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can have a column which is as long as the maximum files size. This is usually limited by the size of hard drive.

In Java the pratical limit is around 2 billion characters which is the maximum size of a String.

You can limit the length if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

CSV is a format that says you are separating your values with commas. That's basically it. There is no maximum in that standard.

Your filesystem has a file-size limit, so that stops it, and your code may have a memory problem is you try to read several gigs, but there is no maximum.

All possible maximums are defined by other factors, not by it being CSV.

Answer (score 3):

CSV is not a standardized format. There is no prescribed length for any 'column' in the file, nor is there any actual formal requirement for the file apart from a list of values separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

CSV files don't have a limit on the maximum size except memory constraints.

However, I feel that it would be a very bad architecture using such a big CSV file in your application.

Comment: I would rather suggest to go for a proper database oriented architecture like, for example, you can use MS Access if you wanta Microsoft product.