# Parsing CSV files using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, csv

I'm trying to create a program, which reads CSV files from a directory, using a regex it parses each line of the file and displays the lines after matching the regex pattern.
For instance if this is the first line of my csv file

```
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
```

my output should be

```
1997 Ford E350 ac, abs, moon 3000.00
```

I don't want to use any existing CSV libraries. I'm not good at regex, I've used a regex I found on net but its not working in my program
This is my source code, I'll be grateful if any one tells me where and what I"ve to modify in order to make my code work. Pls explain me.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


public class RegexParser {

private static Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
private static CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
String pattern = "\"([^\"]*)\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)";

void regexparser( CharBuffer cb)
{ 
    Pattern linePattern = Pattern.compile(".*\r?\n");
    Pattern csvpat = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher lm = linePattern.matcher(cb);
    Matcher pm = null;

    while(lm.find())
    {   
        CharSequence cs = lm.group();
        if (pm==null)
            pm = csvpat.matcher(cs);
            else
                pm.reset(cs);
        if(pm.find())
                     {

            System.out.println( cs);
                      }
        if (lm.end() == cb.limit())
        break;

        }

    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    RegexParser rp = new RegexParser();
    String folder = "Desktop/sample";
    File dir = new File(folder);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for( File entry: files)
    {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(entry);
        FileChannel channel = fin.getChannel();
        int cs = (int) channel.size();
        MappedByteBuffer mbb = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, cs);
        CharBuffer cb = decoder.decode(mbb);
        rp.regexparser(cb);
        fin.close();

    }




}

  }
```

This is my input file

Year,Make,Model,Description,Price

1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00

1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00

1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""","",5000.00

1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!

air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00

I'm getting the same as output where is the problem in my code? why doesn't my regex have any impact on the code?

Comment: "I don't want to use any existing CSV libraries" I suggest you elaborate on this point. Why not? In general Regex is the wrong tool for this job, there are good CSV parsing libraries for this purpose.

Comment: String.split ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html ) won't be enough for you? :)

Comment: @EdC  By using Regex I'm trying to extend this to other file formats, like a generic reader, by using different Regex I can parse different formats. BTW why Regex is wrong tool for this can you expound more?

Comment: @m4tx full CSV support is more complicated than that, you have to deal with quoted content, rows that span multiple lines and escapes.

Comment: @m4tx No its very simple :) I tried it already.

Comment: @niranjan-subramanian basically, CSV is a more complicated format than it seems, there are lots of edge cases to deal with. Regex is really good for searching strings. While it can be used for parsing, other tools do the job better. Not to put too finer point on it, but those CSV parsing libraries were written for a reason.

Comment: @EdC Fine I get your point, but I just want to see the working of my program, I need a simple regex which suffices my need and I don't know  why program doesn't work as I expected it to be.

Comment: @niranjan-subramanian in that case you'll likely get better responses if you provide some more content around what is actually happening, what's going wrong etc.

Comment: @EdC My code doesn't display the output as I'm expecting, instead it displays the content as such in my file. To be more precise the regex I've used in my code doesn't seem to have any impact. So I want to modify regex or any part in my code so that it works fine n displays the proper output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway I've found the fix myself, thanks guys for your suggestion and help.

This was my initial code

```
    if(pm.find()
        System.out.println( cs);
```

Now changed this to

```
  while(pm.find()
  {
 CharSequence css = pm.group();
 //print css
   }
```

Also I used a different Regex. I'm getting the desired output now.

Comment: Hey can you please paste the Regex pattern here.

Comment: \"([^\"]*)\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)

Answer (score 2):

Using regexp seems "fancy", but with CSV files (at least in my opinion) is not worth it. For my parsing I use http://commons.apache.org/csv/. It has never let me down. :)

Comment: Ya I understand, reinventing the wheel isn't a good idea, but at least for learning purpose I need a solution for my program and that's why I've raised my question here.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : `[ \t]*+"[^"\r\n]*+"[ \t]*+|[^,\r\n]*+` with this code :

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[ \t]*+\"[^\"\r\n]*+\"[ \t]*+|[^,\r\n]*+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Do actions
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Take care of errors
}
```

But yeah, if it's not a very critical demand do try to use something that already working : )

Comment: Do I have to insert any escape sequence in your pattern, I'm getting misplaced constructs if I use your pattern

Answer (score 0):

Take the advice offered and do not use regular expressions to parse a CSV file. The format is deceptively complicated in the way it can be used.

The following answer contains links to wikipedia and the RFC describing the CSV file format:

- [field size limitation of csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971542/field-size-limitation-of-csv-file/9972468#9972468)

Comment: That's all fine, but I just want to know why isn't my code working, I"m not able to crack the wrong part in my code