# Is there a way to add a comment line to a CSV file used by Liquibase's loadData changeset?

Tags: csv, liquibase

I have Liquibase loading data using loadData from a .csv file. I'd like to be able to add comment lines before some of the lines. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: Comments are not supported in CSV formated files. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971542/field-size-limitation-of-csv-file/9972468#9972468

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently possible without writing your own custom `loadCommentedData` tag.

Internally, Liquibase uses the open source [OpenCSV library](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and it does not have support for commented lines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible using "#" as a comment pattern or some custom pattern specified by parameter `commentLineStartsWith` like this:

`<loadData commentLineStartsWith="" tableName="t_test" file="t_test.csv" separator="," />`

https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3109?focusedCommentId=42905&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-42905